# Worklight 6.1 - requireJS in adapter invocation

Tags: requirejs, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I want to separate my data retrieval from the localstorage synchro with RequireJS.
To do so, i have a module to get data from adapter and store it to window.myData object.
Then i pass another module to run the synchronization from window.myData to localStorage when the loadSuccess is done.

when i call AdapterService.retrieveRoomsFromServer("john", "doe"), the call to worklight is done, but there's a javascript error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'checkEndSynchro' of undefined
```

The undefined seems to be the SynchronizeLocalStorage pass in function parameters of the RequireJS define().

My AdapterService.js:

```
define([ 
    "jquery", 
    "synchronizeLocalStorage"
], function( $, SynchronizeLocalStorage) {

return {

    retrieveRoomsFromServer: function(username, password) {
        this._invokeProcedureGetListRooms(username, password);
    },

    _invokeProcedureGetListRooms: function(user, password) {
        var invocationData = {
                adapter : 'MyHTTPAdapter',
                procedure : 'getListRooms',
                parameters : [user, password]
        };
        var options = {
            onSuccess : this._loadSuccess,
            onFailure : this._loadFailure,
            invocationContext: this
        };
        WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
    },

    _loadSuccess: function(result) {
        var items = result.invocationResult.array;
        var self = result.invocationContext;
        WL.Logger.debug('loading users rooms');
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var id = items[i].id;
            var name = items[i].name;
            var room = {'id':id, 'name':name};
            window.myData.myRooms.push(room);
        }
        window.flags.myRoomsLoaded = true;
        SynchronizeLocalStorage.checkEndSynchro();
    },

        _loadFailure: function(result) {}
       };
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you utilizing `requireJS` in adapters? You cannot include external libraries in adapters. RequireJS is meant for modular loading... which is not the case for adapters, as there may be only 1 XML file and 1 .js file.

Once you deploy an adapter it becomes a Java object which means it will not be able to use external resources, so using requireJS in this context holds no meaning.

Comment: i'm using requireJS on client side code to invoke Adapters' procedures with WL.Client.invokeProcedure.